# During integration tests, objects that are passed as parameter in function in tests, class load time is different

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, integration-testing

In our environment we are processing entities during class load, with Application Listener using spring.factories. In real product all entities are processed as expected.

But in integration tests, if there is a function in test that takes an entity as parameter, this entity is not processed with application listener. For example XEntity is not processed by listener.

```
private fun assertResultIsCorrect(entity: XEntity) {}
```

Workaround solution is converting entity parameter from XEntity to Any in the method signature and cast inside method to actual entity.

I think, in Kotlin, test functions are processed before Spring Context , but i am not sure.

What can be the reason for this behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question can be ignored, because this behavior is caused by the JVM instrumentation that we have. Class load time and instrumentation execution time was causing inconsistency.